# How do I go back to the old repository view on github?

Tags: git, github

Just today github asked me to try the new repositry view and I don't really like it; would like to go back to the old one. Anyone knows how to go back to the old repositriy view?

Don't like this:
[image: github]

Answer (score 1):

I just heard from github support and the solution is as follows:

"you can disable it by selecting the "feature preview" option from the menu, and then disabling the "repository refresh" option."

To be previse here:

[image]